# Cannot copy and paste images *directly* from browser to outlook

Tags: windows, google-chrome, microsoft-outlook-2010

I cannot copy an image directly from Chrome v37 on our intranet to Outlook 2010 when writing an email. This does not affect copying images from public sites, only intranet sites.

I have to copy the image from the browser by selecting "Copy" from the right click menu, then use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> switch to MS Paint, a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste, then copy from MS Paint to Outlook, to paste the image.

Is there a shortcut to eliminate the need for MS Paint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another workaround, somewhat more convenient: click on the Paste button in the ribbon bar, then Paste Special:

[image: Paste button in ribbon bar, Paste Special]

And then choose Bitmap, instead of the default, HTML Format:

[image]

I think this explains why it doesn't work by default. Outlook is trying to paste some HTML with an embedded image (binary data), which Chrome must be converting into a `data:` URI, or perhaps not converting at all, leaving it pointing to an internal URL, and in either case Outlook doesn't know what to do with it, so can't paste it.

Answer (score 2):

Known issue, says Microsoft. No ETA to fix it. It's in the hands of Redmond (mwahahahahhaahaaahhhhhha). https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-outlook/why-cant-i-paste-a-copied-image-into-outlook-2010/370c9c5c-1a5a-4387-99b1-ebd98a6ec106

Comment: I have a work around. But why doesn't outlook allow the direct copy? I know it tries to talk back to the original website... What is it doing??